# Applying Filters to ONLY New Message Body

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I use filtering to tag email tasks as "In Progress" or "Done" etc. by parsing the body of the message. Sometimes I remove tags manually because the task is, after-all, not done, and needs further work to be done on it. The problem is: if I get any reply after that, say for a question that needs answering for the task to be complete, then it RE-TAGs the thread because of the old message body.

I would like the filtering to work on only the new content in the body of a message and ignore the old. I know that gmail creates a new body with old content, but perhaps you know what I mean. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Gmail doesn't support such a feature. It will always scan the entire message body.

If I understand the problem correctly, this is only an issue when you remove an "In Progress" or "Done" tag.

One workaround:

1. When you remove those tags, add a new tag (ex: "No-Filter").
2. Update the "In Progress" and "Done" filters so that it will never add something with the "No-Filter" tag to those labels.